# Incompatible definition of perfect

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

In Herbert Amann's [Analysis I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b137107), a subset $A$ of a metric space is called perfect if each $a\in A$ is a limit point of $A$, and a perfect interval is an interval containing at least two points. The term "perfect interval" also appears in [Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-9221-6) and [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110853698/html?lang=en). I wonder whether this is a common usage, since every topology book I found require a perfect set be closed.

Comment: I don't have a reference to back this up, but I remember that the professor of my topology course did not require perfect subsets to be closed. I think it's an uncommon variant of the usage of the word.

Comment: You might be overlooking something in Amann's book since for over 100 years the terms (in English, at least) "closed" and "perfect" have been pretty much always used (for subsets of a metric space) to mean: **closed** -- every limit point of the set is in the set; **perfect** -- every limit point of the set is in the set AND every point in the set is a limit point of the set. Also, the term [**dense-in-itself**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself#References) is usually used for the property "every point in the set is a limit point of the set". **(continued)**

Comment: Finally, an interval that contains at least two points is often called a [*nondegenerate interval*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nondegenerate+interval%22&filter=0), MUCH more often than "perfect interval" (a term I've never encountered before). Indeed, "perfect interval" is a very poor choice of term, since it has a well established meaning in music theory.